# Abstract class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java

I have done this in JAVA some time ago, I had some classes:

```
-defaultprinter.java
-hpprinter.java
-epsonprinter.java
...
```

the defaultprinter.java class has a method that can be different on each printer

```
public void serial() {
  get-serial-depending-on-brand-method()
}
```

then I have a method that will select what printer to select

```
if(brand.equals("hp"){
  printer = new hpprinter()
} ...
```

How can I do this with Javascript?
I want to have every printer splited in separated files

```
-defaultprinter.js
-hpprinter.js
-epsonprinter.js
...
```

How can I have the common and overridable method

```
const serial = () => {
  get-serial-depending-on-brand-method()
}
```

And how can I select the printer that I want?

```
if(brand == "hp") {
  printer = ??????
} ...
```

Thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need modules, either [commons js style](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules) or [es6 modules style](http://es6-features.org/#ValueExportImport).

After that, you can define regular [javascript classes](http://es6-features.org/#ClassDefinition) and do the subclassing thing.

--

If you doing electron for the first time but have some modern web development background, take a look at the [electron-webpack](https://webpack.electron.build/) project. It demands some default structure, but it worths the effort to get aligned with it.

here goes [a little example](https://github.com/sombriks/little-example-js-modules/blob/master/app/main.js)!